Merged .pdf file created on python is damaged
I'm very new to python. I wanted to merge multiple pdfs - 121 files - in a particular order (since Python merges in an alphabetical order). So, I created a filelist.txt file while merging all the .pdf files (the Github code for this can be found here)
The code -
import sys
from PyPDF2 import PdfWriter, PdfReader

def main():
    
    # Saving arguments
    pdfDir = sys.argv[1]
    if(sys.argv[2].endswith(".pdf") == False):
        filename = sys.argv[2] + ".pdf"
    else:
        filename = sys.argv[2]
    print ("Directory to merge: %s" % pdfDir)
    print ("File to create: %s" % filename)
    
    # Check if path exists, then change directory
    if(os.path.exists(pdfDir) == True):
        print ("Changing to directory")
        os.chdir(pdfDir)
        if(os.path.isfile(filename) == True):
            os.remove(filename)
    else:
        print ("Path doesn't exist")
        sys.exit()

    if(os.path.isfile("filelist.txt") == True):
        print ("Found filelist.txt")
        order = True
    else:
        print ("No filelist.txt, doing in alphabetical order")
        order = False

    files = []
    if(order == True):
        f = open('filelist.txt', 'r')
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if((line.endswith(".pdf") == True) and (os.path.isfile(line) == True)):
                files.append(line)
    else:
        dirFiles = os.listdir('.')
        dirFiles.sort()
        for foundFile in dirFiles:
            if(foundFile.endswith(".pdf") == True):
                files.append(foundFile)
    if(len(files) < 1):
        print ("No files found for merging")
        sys.exit()

    pdfOutput = PdfWriter()
    for pdfFile in files:
        print ("Adding %s" % pdfFile)
        pdfInput = PdfReader(open(pdfFile, "rb"))
        numPages = len(pdfInput.pages)
        for i in range(numPages):
            pdfOutput.add_page(pdfInput.pages[i])
    outputStream = open(pdfFile, "wb")
    pdfOutput.write(outputStream)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if(len(sys.argv) < 3):
        print ("Incorrect number of parameters.")
        print ("Usage: python PDFMerge.py path/to/pdf/dir output.pdf")
        sys.exit()
    main()

But I get an error -
Directory to merge: -f
File to create: /Users/pulaharoy/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-5ae1382c-f51c-4a04-b09b-3f604540bd8b.json.pdf
Path doesn't exist
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit


/opt/anaconda3/envs/pythonforjournalists/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3426: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)

Is there a way to merge all the files through filelist.text?

There are excellent command-line tools for combining PDF files.  ConcurrentPDF (cpdf) and pdftk are both powerful and easy to use.  No programming is required.

As an unrelated side note, we do not use outer parentheses in Python if statements.  That's a bad habit left over from too much C coding.  Also, do not write if x == True:.  Just write if x:.  The code is more flexible and reads better.
